# What exactly mean “No Outbound Networking” in free tier on Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In Google Firebase pricing (https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) table states:

> The Spark plan only allows outbound network requests to Google-owned
>   services.

Does it mean that JS function in web browser (client) page can't call Firebase function and retrieve data in FREE TIER?

Comment: Found probably good answer: "We just can't allow arbitrary REST calls without a credit card. This helps avoid Cloud Functions being used for abuse/malware."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Good catch, that piece of documentation probably should be clarified.

Inbound requests are allowed, as long as you're within your allowed quota. So your app can call a Cloud Function.

Outbound requests for projects on the free plan are only allowed to Google-owned services. So your Cloud Function code can only call google owned web APIs, unless it's on a paid plan.

**Update**: the above applies up to Node.js runtimes up to v8. **From Node.js 10 and upwards your Firebase project needs to be on a paid plan to be able to use Cloud Functions.** For full details on this, see the Firebase [FAQ on Cloud Functions pricing](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#functions-pricing).

Comment: What exactly qualifies as "Google-owned services"? I'm trying to hit `https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?&q=myKeyWord` on a free tier function but my server logs still block it and consider it an "external connection"

Comment: I get a 400 on that URL. What service is supposed to be hosted there?

Comment: https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&q=searchTermHere is the full url actually - apparently the query params are required. It returns basic autocomplete suggestions from google.

Comment: Yeah, it could be that this URL is not whitelisted. I'd suggest [filing a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), to see if it can be added.

Comment: Hello sir, I was even facing problems on requesting app script api from firebase functions. As it was not counted for the  free tier. So I have to switch to paid plan.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen what about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64201186/can-i-use-firebase-cloud-functions-with-mongodb-atlas-running-on-gcp-in-spark-ti

Answer (score 1):

At lowest possible costs (USD 11.53) it is better to have Blaze plan and use REST calls to Firebase functions freely:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

no, they do not talk about JavaScript Functions, they talk about serverless computing functions

https://firebase.google.com/features/functions/

theses functions can make only make http calls to Google Services and e.g. not to Yahoo or Amazon services