# what exactly is outbound networking in firebase

Tags: firebase, networking, outbound

In my news mobile app, I use firebase for the backend APIs and its hosted on firebase itself. Currently im using the free version of firebase. The issue is even though i dont include any non-google API calls other than from the backend APIs itself, the outbound networking quota gets finished, just by opening the app. 
Any idea why is this happening and how to prevent it because im gonna go for the blaze plan and not sure it will cost me big. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly mean “No Outbound Networking” in free tier on Cloud Functions for Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231446/what-exactly-mean-no-outbound-networking-in-free-tier-on-cloud-functions-for-f)

Comment: No. I simply want to know, is calling my backend APIs (firebase hosted) gonna fall into outbound network? If no, any suggestion to catch this issue?

Comment: I think the link in the comment from @DominikŠimoník is correct *outbound requests for projects on the free plan are only allowed to Google-owned services*. So, if you only use google owned services then it wouldn't be an issue. However, we don't know what this means *other than from the backend APIs itself* as if you are calling non-google services from *anywhere* (API, Cloud, *anywhere*) then those count.